# Create .aaf files using .wav and metadata

Tags: audio, metadata, wav

I am working on a web system, where i need to create .aaf files using .wav files and metadata.

Unfortunately, i am not able to get any source to do so.

I will be very grateful if someone can help me in this regard.

TIA.

Comment: What programming language are you using ? What have you tried ?

Comment: @TGrif I am using Javascript/Nodejs and I have tried ffmpeg, i am not able to get any help online.

Comment: This repo seems interesting [link](https://github.com/markreidvfx/pyaaf2) but it is Python. Don't know if that could help in your case, but you can call a python script from Node.js if you want. Show your trying (your js code), data structure of metadata, context so we can try to help you more.